# Python using 'as' for importing modules

Tags: python

If `as` is used to create an alias in python such as

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

why cannot I import using the same alias

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tf import keras
```

Gives me error

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
```

Answer (score 2):

`tf` is not intended to be a keyword or Module name. Searching about `tf` will not be found in the Module list.
See [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/)

Answer (score 0):

The error is beacuse the,

```
from tf import keras
```

directly tries to find a module named `tf` it does not tries to look for variable named tf or any other declaration of `tf` in your code.

We can import a module with a specific name but the loading process is based on module name and not the alias you have created for it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that while importing you have to use the original name as [Because tf is not a module,it is just a nickname for that library.]

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

and at the time of using it you can use

```
tf.keras()
```

(I am not 100% sure,you can try it.)